# Autofac same injected instance not received when manually resolving an InstancePerRequest type

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to have a transaction ID which will be used for logging throughout the request. Trasaction ID is a property in AuditContext,  which in turn will be a singleton per request. I've the below code in Global.asax.cs

```
builder.RegisterType<AuditContext>().As<IAuditContext>().InstancePerRequest();
....
GlobalContainer = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(GlobalContainer);
```

Transaction ID is set in a base api class.

```
public BaseApiController(IAuditContext auditContext, IDispatcher dispatcher = null)
{  
    auditContext.TransactionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

AuditContext object with the correct transaction ID is injected, in below constructor injection usage.

```
public class SapEventLogger : ISapEventLogger
{        
    private IAuditContext auditContext;        

    public SapEventLogger(IAuditContext auditContext)
    {
        this.auditContext = auditContext; //this auditContext object has correct transaction ID
    }

}
```

In case of any exception I want to retrieve the transaction ID and log it. But when I try to manually resolve, I get a new AuditContext object in which the transaction ID is null.

```
public class ServiceExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        using (var scope = GlobalContainer.BeginLifetimeScope(Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
        {
            var auditContext = scope.Resolve<FDP.Services.Common.IAuditContext>();
            transactionID = auditContext.TransactionID; //Transaction ID is null here
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why a new object is created when resolving AuditContext manually. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `BeginLifetimeScope` call you're manually creating a *second* request lifetime rather than using the existing request lifetime. Two request lifetimes equals two instances.

[The solution to this is outlined in the Autofac docs in more detail](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filters-are-singletons) but the short version is to get the request lifetime from the request message in the handler context:

```
// Get the request lifetime scope so you can resolve services.
var requestScope = context.Request.GetDependencyScope();

// Resolve the service you want to use.
var auditContext = requestScope.GetService(typeof(IAuditContext)) as IAuditContext;

// Do the rest of the work in the filter.
auditContext.DoWork();
```

Comment: Thanks @Travis! One more doubt. If AuditContext is registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope, is it possible to resolve it manually outside a Web Api Controller scope where ActionContext(Request) is not available? Its ok to return null if the resolving is not part of a web API request.

Comment: If you can get the Web API request message where the lifetime scope is held, you're good. If you can't, you're stuck. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Oh, and if you register something instance per request and resolve outside a request you'll get an exception, not null.